# Where can I find the below Linux terminal theme?

Tags: terminal, theme

I have seen the below terminal theme a few times like [this](https://youtu.be/3aO9HDQj9do?t=340) video. I *think* it is using the kitty terminal.

I have found some config files [here](https://github.com/SolDoesTech/HyprV4/tree/main/HyprV/kitty) which *might* be relevant but note sure if this will work/how to install.

FWIW I am using Arch Linux.

[image]

Comment: Well, where have you seen it? Where is this image from?

Comment: @terdon have updated original post

Comment: And why do you think those files are connected to the theme you show? That is most probably a zsh theme, maybe one of the ones you can find for oh-my-zsh. Why do you think this might be connected to the files you gave us? Is there something linking them to this theme?

Comment: @terdon the youtube video is installing hyprV4. after installation, he opens the terminal and it is using this theme. the video description contains links to the hyprV4 dot files including the kitty configurations i linked above. However i am still unsure 1) how to install these kitty configs on my machine and 2) if these config files will give me what I want. For instance, it is still unclear how the config files are will display the Arch icon I see in the terminals printscreen.

Comment: Oh, OK, but that has nothing to do with the theme, that is just the theme the author happens to be using. And it has nothing to do with the terminal emulator either. Have a look at https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes  for some other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, all you have to do is exactly what the video you link to shows you. That includes all commands needed to set the system up the way the video's author has it. Anyway, looking through the things that were installed, I noticed they install something called `starship` and that is the thing you are looking for. So if that's all you want, just run

```
sudo pacman -S starship
```

You then need to activate the "[Tokyo Night](https://starship.rs/presets/tokyo-night.html)" theme:

[image: tokyo night screenshot]

You can find all documentation on how to do this at [the starship website](https://starship.rs/).